# Doing a database search and send email

Tags: php, mysql, database

my first time here and I am quite new to coding.

I have a form that takes the values from a customer table when they want to do a return. This values will then be inserted into a return_product table. However, I need to run another script that does a search in this return product table.

The other script needs to count the total of the transactions in the return_product table group by ID number. When there are customers with 3 or more transactions, they will send an email to the manager. However, the email part should not stop the form from being submitted into the database.

The if loop part is to be done by my friend and she's not done with it yet. What if I need to send out all those who exceed 3 transactions? Do I use a while loop?

I require assistance with making the two scripts run concurrently when the form is being submitted.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: if you want help where's your code?

Comment: Sorry, my first post. Wasn't sure how to post my codes in it. I'll try to edit my post.

Comment: There is a stray `'` in your code, which will cause a syntax error.

Comment: You mean the beginning of the codes? That's not part of my codes. I think I might have added it when I edit my post. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count no of records you can use SQL count method to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You can check your condition before inserting values in db and then return respective data like

```
//Get number of records of particular user with query
//Check the limit
If(num_of_records < 3) {
    //Insert data
} else {
    //Send mail
}
```

With this you don't need to write 2 scripts

Comment: What if there are more than one records that needs to be sent out per email? Do I use a while loop?

Comment: You are checking number of records for a specific user right?
Then in that case you dont need to use while loop

Comment: Tried your codes. However, I need the form to still be submitted even when the condition is met (num_of_records > 3). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you wish to add records every time?

Comment: Umm no. I need to check the database for all users who have more than 3 transactions not just a specific user. And then send them all out to the manager to alert him.

Comment: I didnt get your question. You are submitting form filled by one user. and after submitting that form you want db insertions and want to send mail to manager with users having record more that 3 right?

Comment: The records are so called in another table. And when a customer returns the product, it will be transferred to this return_product table. From there, I am supposed to set an alert that searches this table and if a customer or others have 3 transactions in that table, the script will alert the manager of abuse. This check must be run every time the staff submits the data. And the data must always go into the database. Sorry for the confusion.